# Getting this error when you execute the procedure ORA-29270: too many open HTTP requests

Tags: plsql

```
utl_http.end_response(http_resp) ;

-- x_clob response can now be used for extracting text
-- values from specific XML nodes, using XMLExtract
EXCEPTION
    WHEN ERROR_OUT THEN
        error_code := error_code;
        error_desc    := error_desc; ---SQLERRM||' Unhandled Exception';
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
        error_code := '91';
        error_desc    := SQLERRM || ' Unhandled Exception';
        dbms_output.put_line('Error desc:' || error_desc );
 end;
 /
```

Getting Below error after the Procedure execution

> HTTP Request Failed
>       ORA-29270: too many open HTTP requests

Many time this procedure will be executed. 
let me know how to  End some HTTP requests and response  and execute all the Request

Comment: `utl_http.end_response()` is correct.  Is this running in a loop?  Are you hitting any of your exceptions?  Be sure to check in those exception handlers if the connection is open and close there.  It's possible you're hitting your exception handlers and leaving the connection open.

Comment: but now getting same issue --I have the loop in the Procedure for main procedure i am calling one more procedure to extract the response Text values IF (l_resultCode = 'T' AND  l_resultDescription = 'PASS') THEN ADMIN._XML_Processing(Response_Env, err_code , err_mesg);
        if (err_code <> '00') then  error_code := err_code;error_desc := err_mesg; raise error_out; end if;     after this i am ending the  utl_http.end_response(http_resp) ;Error desc:ORA-29273: HTTP request failedORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_HTTP", line 1130ORA-29270: too many open HTTP requests  Please let us know how to handle